# Deleting a UICollectionViewCell from the screen and the SQLite database.

Tags: ios, sqlite, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that has cells that are being populated by a UIImagePickerController, that get pictures from my image library and inserts them into an Array and SQLite db. I have a button on the cell that i want to use to delete it. How do I delete the cell. Tags on the cell are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag(indexPath.item) to button also in the same way as you did to your collection view cell. And in the action method you will get the button as sender. Access sender.tag to get the index path of the right item.